# Pushing view controller when presenting UISearchController over UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented `UISearchController` so that it appears overtop the `UINavigationBar` upon tapping a search icon. After filtering the table, the user should be able to select a row which will push a new view controller. The problem is upon doing so, the search controller is still being shown overtop the navigation bar.

I have researched this and it was suggested you should set `self.definedPresentationContext` to `true`. This does not work when the search bar is presented overtop the navigation bar. When you tap the search icon the keyboard appears but the search bar does not animate in.

Another option I found is to dismiss the search controller in `viewWillDisappear`, by setting `active` to `false`. The problem with this solution is it animates away during the push transition. And when you navigate back, the search is obviously no longer active, therefore the user has lost the search context and all results are shown.

I would like to know how to push a view controller, keep the search active, but not show the search interface overtop of the next view controller. Ideally the search interface would be pushed away to the left as the new view controller is pushed, and return upon swiping back to the search results.

I have tweaked Apple's UIKit Catalog sample code to show the undesired behavior. To reproduce the problem, [download this project](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3f0r2O1K3s2J0m2r1s39/UIKitCatalogiOSCreatingandCustomizingUIKitControls.zip), run it on iPhone, tap the back button, select Search, select Present Over Navigation Bar, tap the search icon, type in a search term, and select a result. Notice the search bar remains visible. Here is the code from `SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if searchController.active {
        //searchController.active = false //undesirably dismisses search, animates away during push, upon going back search is not active
    }
}

@IBAction func searchButtonClicked(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //self.definesPresentationContext = true //causes the search to not appear

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the show but I recently found myself in a similar situation and want to share my experience.

So let's say you have presented your search interface, the user has typed something into the search field and you have showed them some results. Upon selecting a result I push the new view controller to the original navigation controller, that is the navigation controller that contains the view controller which presented the search interface. When I do this, the search interface gets pushed to the left and when you tap the back button, the search interface is brought back and its state (query and results) is preserved.

I should mention that in the controller that contains the searchable content, the one that presents the search interface, I have enabled presentation context.

Also, my search bar is integrated in the header view of the table view that displays the search content, so I don't present the search interface explicitly - when the user taps inside the search field, it automatically goes up and pushes the navigation bar out of the screen. This is the only difference in our setups that I can think of. Anyways, hope this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Lubo! How do you exactly push the detail view controller after pressing a result on the search result table view? You pass it using delegates or something to the root navigation vc?